# Does Windows 10 log where location requests come from?

Tags: windows-10

I noticed in the systray a little icon that said my location was in use. Is there a log that will tell me when/which applications have accessed my location?

Comment: In Settings it lists the apps with access.

Comment: Go to Start  > Settings  > Cortana.
Select Permissions or Permissions & History.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4468240/windows-10-location-service-and-privacy

Comment: I have location access enabled but all the listed apps aren't allowed to use location. What I'm looking for is some sort of an event log that will tell me when a process accesses my location, and what the PID and process name are.